# Latitude's "Enable location sharing" settings disables automatically

Tags: google-latitude

I want my latitude friends to see my location. However, I am seeing that this setting disables automatically after few minutes, even after enabling again and again.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you using any battery saver applications? or anything like that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Google Latitude's service has been discontinued since August 2013.